# event handling iron python

Tags: python, .net, ironpython

If there are lets say 4 buttons, all with the same Click event, how can I find out which button was pressed?

if the event looks like this `def Button_Click(self, sender, e):` I'm sure I can compare sender to my buttons somehow. But how?

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: I'm using WPF with Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've never used IronPython so I don't know how much help this will be, but what I usually do when trying to figure out these things in regular python is to `print type(sender)` , `print sender` and `print dir(sender)` to console(or output to a file if you don't have a console available).

This should help you figure out what exactly is the "sender" parameter. In the simplest case it could be the button itself so a simple `==` will work to know which button it was. Or it could have a method/property that gets you the button object. In which case, `dir(sender)` might contain an obvious one, or if not, google the class name gotten from `type(sender)` and see if you can find any docs.

Comment: thanks sender was actually the textbox and i just had to use ==

Comment: Glad to have been of service :)

Comment: PS: These are the times when I feel like python's total lack of type information is annoying. Basically, in APIs that don't specify what you should give them or what they will send via callbacks. I realize that this is a problem with documentation rather than the language but at least with types the documentation *has* to be there

Comment: Yes especially IronPythons Documentation is really lacking, but I guess that has to be expected from Open Source Projects...